# How to do preg_replace in java

Tags: java, regex

I have looked around stackoverflow for preg_replace solution and stumbled on some but has not help with my problem, yet.

I'm trying to replace portion of a url to with another string but no joy.

Here is what I have done

```
    String htmlString = "http://localhost/web/test/11/soap/testserver.php";
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("http://(.*)/soap/testserver.php");
    Matcher m = patt.matcher(htmlString);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(htmlString.length());
    String text = "local.test";
    while (m.find()) {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(text));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I get an output "local.test.php" but I like to get "http://local.host/soap/testserver.php"

what am i doing wrong

Thanks in advance.

Comment: oops, long day.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just match all the characters before the string `/soap` and capture all the chaarcter from `/soap`. In the replacement part add th captured group index `\1` with the string `http://local.host`

Regex:

```
^.*(/soap.*)$
```

Replacement string:

```
http://local.host$1
```

Code:

```
System.out.println("http://localhost/web/test/11/soap/testserver.php".replaceAll("^.*(/soap.*)$", "http://local.host$1"));
```

Output:

```
http://local.host/soap/testserver.php
```